# Unity How to achieve orbit swapping effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let me get straight to the point. So, have a look at below picture.
[image]

Try to imagine this with the context of 3d. you are in first orbit and when the user taps you want to be in second orbit which is inside the circle. I tried doing this with animation but cant have better control over it and obviously not desired result. Let me show even better picture. Same thing as of first picture.
[image]

[image]

So, anybody have idea about any formula or code to move ball in such a way.

Comment: Do you want it to slide in from one orbit to the other, snap in, or rotate around the edge of the red/white/blue torus?  What are you currently doing to get it rotating in the first orbit?

Comment: @Foggzie Rotate

Comment: @Foggzie Currently I am using anchor point method to get it rotating in the first orbit. I kept a empty game object in the origin and called it pivot point. and made the ball the child of that having the radius equal to that of above orbit. and I rotate the anchor point

Comment: Take that concept (anchoring with an empty `GameObject`) and apply it again to however you want the sub-oribit movements to function.  If that's not enough info, this question is a bit too specific and would be better suited for (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) with more details about what you've tried already.

Comment: @Foggzie Thank you I fixed this with the concept of nested anchoring

Comment: @Foggzie I am now laughing at the solution. There is no formula needed but just some nested anchoring